# Props appear like undefined when a children is passing too

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I try to pass a `children` and `props` to my component, the children pass well, but the props come like undefined, I cannot figure why.  When I don't use children that's work fine. A little snippet to understand the problem.
`the function`

```
import React from "react";

export function PropsChildren({ children }, props) {
  console.log("info props", props.name, props.age);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Props name is {props.name}</p>
      <p>Props age is {props.age}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`the call`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
//import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { PropsChildren } from "./props/props_children";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <PropsChildren name="Knupel" age={46}>
      {document}
    </PropsChildren>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

console return
`info props undefined undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`props` is not the second argument. The props and present the the first object and `children` is also present there.

```
export function PropsChildren({ children, ...props }) {
  console.log("info props", props.name, props.age);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Props name is {props.name}</p>
      <p>Props age is {props.age}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's work like a charm, but why it's necessary to write `...` before `props`?

Comment: @Knupel first argument contain three properties `{children, age, name}`. You have destrucutured `children` now you want to get all other props except children and then store it in a variable as object. So that's why we use `...props`. You can also destrcuture other props `export function PropsChildren({ children, name, age })`